# This dependency was not found - mevn stack

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, vue.js

I am trying to make an combination with **nodejs/mongoDB** and **Vue.js**.

Online I found this tutorial:
https://medium.com/@anaida07/mevn-stack-application-part-1-3a27b61dcae0

I got far into the tutorial, my nodejs server is running and my vue.js is also running.

Now when i try to include postservice i get a big errormessage.
I'm not sure in what package its supposed to be though and how to fix it.

the error-message it provides me is :

```
ERROR  Failed to compile with 1 errors                                 19:09:01
```

This dependency was not found:

```
* @/services/PostsService in ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/selector.js?type=script&index=0!./src/components/Posts.vue

    To install it, you can run: npm install --save @/services/PostsService
```

My **package.json** looks like this

```
{
  "name": "server",
  "version": "5.3.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "src/app.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "./node_modules/nodemon/bin/nodemon.js src/app.js",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "cors": "^2.8.4",
    "express": "^4.16.3",
    "morgan": "^1.9.0",
    "nodemon": "^1.17.3"
  }
}
```

My **posts.vue** looks like this

```
<template>
  <div class="posts">
    <h1>Posts</h1>
    This file will list all the posts.

    <div v-for="post in posts">
      <p>
        <span><b>{{ post.title }}</b></span><br />
        <span>{{ post.description }}</span>
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import PostsService from '@/services/PostsService'
export default {
  name: 'posts',
  data () {
    return {
      posts: []
    }
  },
  mounted () {
    this.getPosts()
  },
  methods: {
    async getPosts () {
      const response = await PostsService.fetchPosts()
      this.posts = response.data
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

My **PostService.js** has the following content

```
import Api from '@/services/Api'

export default {
  fetchPosts () {
    return Api().get('posts')
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you create PostsService.js? The medium post has this => _Let’s create a new file in the same location as PostsService.js . This is going to be used for hitting the posts api endpoint which we create a while ago in the server folder._

Comment: @Vasan yes i created the file, i updated the question with the content of it

Comment: Perhaps a typo in your post but make sure the file name and path matches what you import. You have `PostService.js` in this question but you access  `PostsService` (note additional 's'). Also, it's inside services directory.

Comment: that was one of my issues indeed! i also changed @/ to .../ and it seems to work. Thanks!